Rx cancellation and race condition
I have an async method that receives data from Rx Observable and writes it to a file. Give this method a cancellationToken and cancel it at some random time.
This method is implemented with await Observable.Do(...).ToTask(cancellationToken). However, the Observable's onNext event may occur after the cancel is complete, and lead to the use of a disposed object. You can see in the following message that the threads between onNext and finally are not the different.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var observable = Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
        .Timestamp();

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = SaveAsync(observable, "abc.txt", cts.Token);

    Console.ReadKey();

    cts.Cancel();

    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task SaveAsync(
    IObservable<Timestamped<long>> observable,
    string filepath,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);

    try
    {
        await observable.Do(timestamp =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            Console.WriteLine($"Do a thread={Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");

            writer.WriteLine(timestamp);

            Console.WriteLine($"Do b");
        }).ToTask(cancellationToken);
    }
    finally
    {
        writer.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine($"Finally thread={Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
    }
}

Do a thread=4
Do b
Do a thread=4
Do b
Finally thread=1
Do a thread=4

If I change the implementation to await Observable.Do(...).TakeWhile(_ => !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested), there is no race condition since the threads between onNext and finally are the same.
static async Task SaveAsync(
   IObservable<Timestamped<long>> observable,
   string filepath,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);

    try
    {
        await observable.Do(timestamp =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            Console.WriteLine($"Do a thread={Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");

            writer.WriteLine(timestamp);

            Console.WriteLine($"Do b");
        }).TakeWhile(_ => !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
    finally
    {
        writer.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine($"Finally thread={Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
    }
}

Do a thread=4
Do b
Do a thread=4
Do b
Do a thread=4
Do b
Finally thread=4

For me ToTask(cancellationToken) is simpler and more natural for me, is there a way to avoid race condtion in case of different threads? Or is there a better way to implement this method?

Check this, pay attention on TakeUntil
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Text;

internal class Program
{

    internal class MyStreamSwiter : StreamWriter
    {
        public MyStreamSwiter(Stream stream) : base(stream)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) : base(stream, encoding)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize) : base(stream, encoding, bufferSize)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(Stream stream, Encoding? encoding = null, int bufferSize = -1, bool leaveOpen = false)
            : base(stream, encoding, bufferSize, leaveOpen)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(string path) : base(path)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(string path, bool append) : base(path, append)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding) : base(path, append, encoding)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize) : base(path, append,
            encoding, bufferSize)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(string path, FileStreamOptions options) : base(path, options)
        {
        }

        public MyStreamSwiter(string path, Encoding encoding, FileStreamOptions options) : base(path, encoding,
            options)
        {
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            Console.WriteLine("StreamWriter disposed");
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var observable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
            .Timestamp();

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = SaveAsync(observable, "abc.txt", cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

        Console.ReadKey();

        cts.Cancel();

        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Shouldn't be here");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task SaveAsync(
        IObservable<Timestamped<long>> observable,
        string filepath,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Observable.Using(
            () => new MyStreamSwiter(filepath),
            writer => observable
                .TakeUntil(cancellationToken.ToObservable())
                .Do(timestamp =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Do a thread={Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}, {timestamp}");

                    writer.WriteLine(timestamp);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Do b, {timestamp}");
                })
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine($"Finally thread={Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}"))
        )
        .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
        .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
        ;
    }
}

internal static class Extensions
{
    public static IObservable<Unit> ToObservable(this CancellationToken ct,
        bool throwIfCancellationRequested = false) =>
        Observable.Create<Unit>(observer => ct.Register(() =>
            {
                if (throwIfCancellationRequested)
                    observer.OnError(new OperationCanceledException(ct));
                else
                {
                    observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
            })
        );
}

Tail of the output:
Do a thread=6, 12@12/19/2024 6:36:59 AM +00:00
Do b, 12@12/19/2024 6:36:59 AM +00:00
Do a thread=6, 13@12/19/2024 6:36:59 AM +00:00
Do b, 13@12/19/2024 6:36:59 AM +00:00
Do a thread=6, 14@12/19/2024 6:36:59 AM +00:00
Do b, 14@12/19/2024 6:36:59 AM +00:00
Do a thread=6, 15@12/19/2024 6:36:59 AM +00:00
Do b, 15@12/19/2024 6:36:59 AM +00:00
Finally thread=6
StreamWriter disposed


It doesn't run to the Finally section. I create a class LogStreamWriter : StreamWriter and override its Dispose() to check if the writer is disposed. In your method the writer doesn't be disposed.

Did the same - writer is disposed

Thanks for details. I copy all and paste, still no disposed. I guess it could be a potential bug with different versions of .NET? Mine is .NET Framework 4.8.

@cbel Got it, I'm using .net8 under linux and probably there is a difference in threads compartment. So I added ObserveOn - check pls

Observable.Using(...).ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default) still no disposed.

Hmmm. There is a difference indeed either between FW, OS or Rx versions. Let's try to add .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default) also. And possibly add [MTAThread] attribute over Main method, but this is already a desperation :-) Using System.Reactive 6.0.0 BTW

Also note .ConfigureAwait(false) over Save method

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
